# How do I pass a data frame to a function, and return a new data frame with the columns rearranged?

Tags: r

I have this MRA_DF data frame. I want to pass this data frame into a function called AccountMRA. From here, I want to remove the MRA_DF$speed column, make the MRA_DF$price column the first column, and make the MRA_DF$dist the second column. Then I want to return this. I can not figure this out.

This data frame = MRA_DF

```
    speed dist  price
1     4    2  200
2     4   10  100
3     7    4  300
4     7   22  400
5     8   16  100
6     9   10  200
```

Ideal output:

```
     price  dist
1     200 2
2     100 10
3     300 4
4     400 22
5     100 16
6     200 10
```

Comment: Use `MRA_DF[ ,c(3,2)]`

Comment: Or use column names instead of indices: `MRA_DF[c("price", "dist")]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr package, you can make a function that can take in a column to drop and a list of column names in a specific order:

```
library(dplyr)

# create dataframe
MRA_DF = data.frame(speed = c(4, 4, 7, 7, 8, 9), dist = c(2, 10, 4, 22, 16, 10), price = c(200, 100, 300, 400, 100, 200))

# AccountMRA takes in a dataframe, column order, and a column to drop
#' @param colorder --> list of column names in specific order
#' @param todrop --> column name to drop
#' @param data1 --> dataframe to manipulate
#' @return --> return formatted dataframe
AccountMRA <- function(data1, colorder = c('price', 'dist'), todrop = 'speed'){
    toreturn <- as.data.frame(data1
                        %>% dplyr::select(-eval(parse(text = todrop))))
    return(toreturn[, colorder])
}

AccountMRA(MRA_DF, colorder = c('price', 'dist'), todrop = 'speed')

# has the following output:
#   price dist
# 1   200    2
# 2   100   10
# 3   300    4
# 4   400   22
# 5   100   16
# 6   200   10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic R subsetting:

```
MRA_DF = data.frame(speed = c(4, 4, 7, 7, 8, 9), dist = c(2, 10, 4, 22, 16, 10), price = c(200, 100, 300, 400, 100, 200))

 df <- MRA_DF[,c("price","dist")]

# df
#  price dist
#1   200    2
#2   100   10
#3   300    4
#4   400   22
#5   100   16
#6   200   10
```